# Не могу работать с grid

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

Я хотел создать интерфейс для игры и использовал для этого tkinter. Хотел расставить по таблице, расставил но вышло не так я ожидал.

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.geometry('192x393+500+150')
root.title("Угадай число!")

variant = Entry(root, bg="black",
                      fg="white",
                      font="Arial, 30",
                      justify="center").grid(row=1, columnspan=2)
b1 = Button(text="1").grid(column=0, row=4)
b2 = Button(text="2").grid(column=1, row=4)
b3 = Button(text="3").grid(column=2, row=4)
b4 = Button(text="4").grid(column=0, row=3)
b5 = Button(text="5").grid(column=1, row=3)
b6 = Button(text="6").grid(column=2, row=3)
b7 = Button(text="7").grid(column=0, row=2)
b8 = Button(text="8").grid(column=1, row=2)
b9 = Button(text="9").grid(column=2, row=2)
b0 = Button(text="0").grid(row=5, columnspan=2)



root.mainloop()
```

Как сейчас выглядеть таблица, а должно быть как в калькуляторе:

[image: как сейчас выглядеть таблица, а должно быть как в калькуляторе]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если убрать ограничение по размеру окна, то получится такой результат:

[image: Скрин 1]

Здесь видно, что текстовое поле расширяет колонки сетки, так что 2 и 3 колонки уезжали за границы окна.

Если для текстового поля задать параметр `columnspan=4`, то станет немного лучше:

[image: Скрин 2]

Остается задать для 4-й колонки (на которой нет кнопок, но на нее вылазит текстовое поле) параметр `weight=1` ("вес"), чтобы она расширялась (а первые три наоборот сузились, т.к. у них по умолчанию параметр `weight=0`, колонки с большим "весом" как бы вытесняют колонки с меньшим "весом"):

[image: Скрин 3]

Код с исправлениями:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
# root.geometry('192x393+500+150')
root.title("Угадай число!")

variant = Entry(root, bg="black",
                      fg="white",
                      font="Arial, 30",
                      justify="center").grid(row=1, columnspan=4)

b1 = Button(text="1").grid(column=0, row=4)
b2 = Button(text="2").grid(column=1, row=4)
b3 = Button(text="3").grid(column=2, row=4)
b4 = Button(text="4").grid(column=0, row=3)
b5 = Button(text="5").grid(column=1, row=3)
b6 = Button(text="6").grid(column=2, row=3)
b7 = Button(text="7").grid(column=0, row=2)
b8 = Button(text="8").grid(column=1, row=2)
b9 = Button(text="9").grid(column=2, row=2)
b0 = Button(text="0").grid(row=5, columnspan=2)

root.grid_columnconfigure(3, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Также учитывайте, что в таких строках:

```
b1 = Button(text="1").grid(column=0, row=4)
```

вы в переменную записываете не объект кнопки, а результат вызова метода `grid`, который всегда `None`. Чтобы потом не было неожиданностей, нужно сначала записать в переменную кнопку, а потом от переменной вызывать метод `grid`:

```
b1 = Button(text="1")
b1.grid(column=0, row=4)
```

---

Еще вариант решения проблемы разъезжающихся кнопок без необходимости тонкой настройки сетки - размещать текстовое поле в основном окне, а кнопки в отдельном фрейме, и этот фрейм уже в основном окне:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
# root.geometry('192x393+500+150')
root.title("Угадай число!")

variant = Entry(root, bg="black",
                      fg="white",
                      font="Arial, 30",
                      justify="center")

variant.pack()

frame = Frame(root)
Button(frame, text="1").grid(column=0, row=4)
Button(frame, text="2").grid(column=1, row=4)
Button(frame, text="3").grid(column=2, row=4)
Button(frame, text="4").grid(column=0, row=3)
Button(frame, text="5").grid(column=1, row=3)
Button(frame, text="6").grid(column=2, row=3)
Button(frame, text="7").grid(column=0, row=2)
Button(frame, text="8").grid(column=1, row=2)
Button(frame, text="9").grid(column=2, row=2)
Button(frame, text="0").grid(row=5, columnspan=2)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Скриншот:

[image: Скрин альтернативного решения]

Answer (score 2):

*Никогда не понимал принцип работы колонок и строк в tkinter))*

Предлагаю вам, для упрощения работы с кнопками, добавить их в массив, предварительно расставив там в нужном порядке, а затем уже расставить их в цикле.

При этом, строку с установкой размера окна нужно будет убрать: `root.geometry('192x393+500+150')`

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Угадай число!")
# запрещаем изменять размер окна
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

variant = Entry(root, bg="black",
                  fg="white",
                  font="Arial, 30",
                  justify="center").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

btn_list = [
    "1", "2", "3",
    "4", "5", "6",
    "7", "8", "9",
    "0"
]

r = 1
c = 0

for i in btn_list:
    Button(root, text=i, width = 10).grid(row=r, column=c)
    c += 1
    if c > 4:
        c = 0
        r += 1

root.mainloop()
```

**Получаем такой результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если вам нужен именно ваш размер окна, то нужно просто поменять максимальное количество колонок: в цикле установки кнопок, вместо `if c > 4:` делаем `if c > 1:`. В параметре установки поля ввода *Entry* значение `columnspan` делаем равным `15`

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Также хотелось бы добавить информацию касательно привязки кнопок к вводу. Сделать это можно через лямбда-функцию.

Для этого переносим размещение `variant` в отдельную строку

```
variant = Entry(root, bg="black",fg="white",font="Arial, 30",justify="center")
variant.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)
```

Добавляем функцию

```
def wirte(key):
    global memory
    variant.insert(END, key)
```

И в цикле, перед объявлением кнопки определяем её функцию:

```
cmd = lambda x=i: write(x)
Button(root, text=i, width = 10, command = cmd).grid(row=r, column=c)
```